# Nodejs. Subscribe to EventEmitter.emits and only execute on certain conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

I am trying to implement something like the following: (See the section entitled "A command-line interface should be bipolar."

http://michaelbrooks.ca/deck/jsconf2013/#/74

Basically I want something that looks like:

```
var argv = require('optimist')
        .argv;

var em = require('events').EventEmitter;
var EventEmitter = new em();

var bell = function ringBell() {
console.log('ring');
}

EventEmitter.emit('doorOpen');

if (argv.t) {
    EventEmitter.on('doorOpen', bell);
}
```

How I am actually using this is a little more complex, but I want to emit certain things right away, and then have the possibility to subscribe to them later and have the output shown to them if certain things are true (in this case -t flag is given) and if not, nothing happens.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to subscribe BEFORE the event is emitted. Put the "if(argv.t)" block before you emit the "doorOpen" event. Even if your app is super-complex you need to attach the event handler before it is emitted.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks a lot. If you submit that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe BEFORE the event is emitted. Put the "if(argv.t)" block before you emit the "doorOpen" event. Even if your app is super-complex you need to attach the event handler before it is emitted.

For example:

```
if (argv.t) {
    em.on('doorOpen', bell);
}

em.emit('doorOpen');
```